# Cassandra latency metric flat

Tags: cassandra, metrics, cassandra-3.0

I face the problem about Cassandra latency metric flat on Cassandra version 3.0 and later.

After that I have found bug relate with this issue as below URL.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11752

The detail show that this problem has been solved in C* version 2.2.8, 3.0.9, 3.8. But after I have tested on Apace Cassandra version 3.0.9, The result of latency still show flat line.

I used jconsole to monitor Cassandra read and write latency. It showed the same latency value all the time when I was running load test. Whereas M1_rate and request count have movement as normal.

Are there any suggestion for solving this issue?

Comment: What is "Cassandra latency metric flat" and why do you think it is an issue?

Comment: I mean when I was monitoring Cassandra on latency by using jvisualvm or nodetool proxyhistrograms. I saw Cassandra latency graph like horizontal line (flat line). There is no spike, no movement even there have heavy load. It is unusual and doesn't make sense. But when I load on Cassandra version 2.1 or 2.0, the result of latency look normal.